# MySQL - Best Internal Error Handling Technique for AWS RDS and RR Support

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, error-handling, amazon-rds, read-replication

We have a custom-built CRM system that's deployed on AWS RDS. Our FE and BE systems are JavaScript, and the database prohibits the JS devs from directly manipulating the database. They must go through predefined APIs or a controlled query system. It works beautifully and the devs have never managed to hurt the database :)

**UPDATE: The controlled query system enforces JSON constructs as the only method the front-end and back-end systems have to update, insert and delete records. The Database monitors the JSON constructs and processes them accordingly, which includes stripping and denying data and requests that don't meet specific guidelines.**

The Database has its own internal error reporting system that has worked very well, mainly because the JS devs often don't report errors from stored procedure calls that fail (grr). So the Database reports these errors in a tracking table. That way we can see what bad payloads the JS devs are sending or catch the occasional error in our SQL.

**UPDATE: The internal error reporting system is exactly that; any time a stored procedure triggers an unhandled error, it writes the error out to an error table that is monitors by the Database team. It exists at the core database level and has nothing to do with the query control system.**

The problem is we've deployed a Read Replica of our database, and now the internal error reporting system is rendered useless on RR calls that fail.

Is there a technique or method where the RR can somehow send write-out calls to the master? Or do I have to switch over to a log file system? If I have to do that, it pretty much requires us to abandon our master error table tracking...

So I guess the core question is: What internal MySQL error reporting system and technique should we consider for an enterprise-scale CRM database that utilizes Read Replicas?

Thanks!

Comment: "They must go through predefined APIs or a controlled query system": how is it implemented?

Comment: "Database has its own internal error reporting system that has worked very well": is this a part of the "controlled query system" or a different thing? Could you please expand a little bit on how your current system is implemented?

Comment: @Quassnoi I've updated the description above to address your questions.

Comment: I'm sorry about being picky. It looks to me that you're just giving different names to the common patterns just about every other web application on the planet is doing. Your "controlled query system", is it JS code taking JSON requests and transforming it into database queries? When you're saying "The Database monitors the JSON constructs": is the monitoring code written in JS or lives in stored procedures in the database? Is the "internal reporting system" implemented in JS as well?

Comment: @Quassnoi you're trying to help - not being picky at all - I appreciate the inquiry. The Database is the only system logging the errors/failures. While the JavaScript system has its own error logs, the DB is responsible for reporting its own internal errors (including bad payloads from JS). The difference with our system is the Database control the incoming JSON and how it's executed - as such we have complete control over what we allow the JavaScript systems to do. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RDS read replica cannot send a query to the source instance.

> What internal MySQL error reporting system and technique should we consider for an enterprise-scale CRM database that utilizes Read Replicas?

Detect and report invalid payloads in the back-end code that processes requests, not in stored procedures.

Your code can log the bad requests to whichever instance you want. I mean, you could log an error to the source instance even though the request (once validated) would have resulted in executing a stored procedure on the read replica instance.

But I would recommend logging bad requests to some other logging system, not to the database. The bad requests do not relate to any other data in the database, and it just adds more storage load and query load to be logging bad requests in the database.

AWS currently provides a service called [Centralized Logging with OpenSearch](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/centralized-logging-with-opensearch/). This sounds like a likely candidate to which to send reports of bad requests, but I have not used this AWS service so I can't report any experience with it. It's just an example of the kind of thing I'm talking about.

Logging systems are generally simpler and less expensive than using a full-blown RDBMS for that task.

Comment: Yah I can't seem to determine how that works with RDS in a controlled capacity. One nice thing about our own internal log system is we can choose exactly what's written out to the log, so very complex SP calls that error out can include additional data. What we really need is an external log system that can be called through a MySQL call so we can manually write out what we're already doing internally... but I don't see OpenSearch supporting that... any additional thoughts?

Comment: OpenSearch helps to aggregate logs of different types, including application logs. I'm talking about using an application log to send error messages, and you can include any information you want in application error messages.

Comment: Really you don't need a special service at all. The old school way is to simply write errors to a designated file on the same hosts where the app runs.

Answer (score 1):

The general direction is what Bill said in his answer. I'll just add some AWS-specific flavor.

In AWS, the go-to place for error logging is [CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/cloudwatch/). It's super easy to set up and use, and dirt cheap compared to storing your error logs in RDS.

The flow is like this:

1. [Create a log group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_CreateLogGroup.html). It's done once, and the expectation that it lives for as long as your application is in business (hopefully years). It's an analog of your error table.
2. Once an instance of your back-end application starts, [create a log stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_CreateLogStream.html). Put the code to do that into the application startup code.
3. Wrap your validation logic and database calls into try-catch blocks. If a validator or a database call throws an exception, [put an event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutLogEvents.html) with the exception description into the log stream.

There is a nice library called [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston), with a [CloudWatch plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-cloudwatch), that can handle all this for you.

CloudWatch has some rudimentary analytic and search capabilities, which might be enough for your use case. If it's not, you can use a plethora of services like Quicksight (AWS native); Kibana, Splunk, NewRelic (third-party) etc, all of which integrate easily with CloudWatch.

Describing them in detail is beyond the scope of this answer, but just about every single one of them is more convenient and operationally cheaper than storing the log data in RDS.

Comment: So does the CloudWatch solution allow for me to write out to the log files from the MySQL code itself? We need the ability to write out custom errors from within MySQL. My understanding is that requires some sort of integrated API within the language itself. I haven't seen any actual examples of writing out to a CloudWatch log from MySQL... are you aware of any?

Comment: @Floobinator: no, MySQL doesn't have anything like that. This pattern you're employing (using the database as an API) has its uses, especially on early stages of development, but it has its shortcomings as well, which might be becoming obvious to you. It's much easier to develop complex applications if you treat your database as a storage layer and abstract it using the [repository pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). Yes it does sound like corporate bullshit if you're not used to it. And yes, it's there for a reason. I'm sorry I don't have a better answer for you.

Comment: @Floobinator: that said, there should be something calling this "controlled query system" from the JS code. What happens if the payload fails validation or something else happens? Does it have a way to report it to the caller (besides writing stuff to the error log table)? If yes, there is nothing stopping you from implementing the two approaches in parallel on the master (where the writes are allowed) and fall back to JS logging only on the replicas.